¿si en el manual HP dice q mi laptop tiene 16gb de ram como maximo(2 x 8), puedo ponerle (2 x 16) para tener 32gb?
Quiero ponerle el maximo de ram posible a mi laptom HP 250 g7 de decima generacion con intel i7, pero mi problema es q oficialmente soporta como maximo 16gb de ram (2x8) pero en paginas como "crucial" e incluso videos de youtube dicen q si soporta 32gb de ram (2x16) alguien probo esto y le funciono? puede ser q soporte 32gb pero solo use 16gb y no aproveche toda la ram?

Este no es el lugar para este tipo de preguntas amigo jaja. Acá es un lugar para preguntas de programación. Tienes que ir a HP con el modelo exacto y consultar, como este sujeto -> https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Hardware-and-Upgrade-Questions/Max-memory-for-HP-250-G7-notebook/td-p/7160856

En general sí es posible agregar memoria y cambiar componentes. En una notebook es más complicado. Pero para asegurarte mira la información que provea el fabricante o al menos la del CPU. En general el CPU dice con cuánta memoria es compatible. También deberías ver si la placa madre tiene algún límite
